# Thymeleaf игнорирует атрибуты и не обрабатывает страницу

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Есть контроллер

```
@Controller
public class FirstController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloPage(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                            Model model){

        model.addAttribute("message", name);
        return "first/hello";
    }
}
```

И есть view **hello.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <p th:text="${message}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Ввожу необходимые параметры:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello?name=Tom
```

Но все что выводит страница это "*Hello world!*"

**P.S.** Я пока работаю со `spring core` и поэтому конфиги пришлось писать руками, вот что находиться в конфигах:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.nosferat.springapp")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        var viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Может есть какая то связь с конфигом

Comment: пропал Сергей...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Ваш Spring ничего не знает о `Thymeleaf`
Предположу, что когда вы откроете исходный код вашей HTML страницы, то ва там увидите пустой тег

```
<p th:text="${message}"></p>
```

Это значит, что он не обработан шаблонизатором.

Для того чтобы Thymeleaf его обработал, необходимо:

- Объявить бин c `SpringTemplateEngine` от `Thymeleaf`, который будет обрабатывать шаблоны
- Создать бины Template Resolver и `ThymeleafViewResolver` с прокинутым в него Template Engine, которые будут находить необходимые шаблоны и передавать их Thymeleaf

Итого:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.nosferat.springapp")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    
        return templateResolver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
        return templateEngine;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Подробнее можно прочитать в официальных  туториалах [Thymeleaf+Spring](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html):

- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html